# Contradictory pointers in an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I came across some "weird" behaviour in C, at least something I did not expect. Consider this following line of code:

```
int arrayB[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
printf("%d\n", (arrayB+1)[1]);
```

This works fine as `(arrayB + 1)[1]` translates to `*(arrayB+1 +1)` which is the third element of `arrayB` (thus it prints 3 as expected)

However, consider the below code where I initialize a 2D array called `arrayA` (with 5 arrays of 10 ints, each `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`)

```
int ** arrayA = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arrayA[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        arrayA[i][j] = j;
    }
}

printf("%d\n", *(arrayA+1)[2]);
```

This code does not raise a warning, and it claims that `*(arrayA+1)[2]` is an int type. However.. it seems that it should be (since array subscript has higher priority over dereference operator), `*(arrayA+1)[2]` translates to `*(arrayA+3)` which is of type `int *`, since `arrayA` is a `int **` that Even further is that this is allowed after:

`*(arrayA+1)[2] = 1;`

But how is this possible? It seems as if I am assigning a `int` to a `int *`... which typically raises a warning.

Comment: This is *not* a 2D array but only a poor emulation of it. C has native multi-dimensional arrays. Don't complicate your life unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it seems that ... `*(arrayA+1)[2]` translates to `*(arrayA+3)`

No, you dropped a `*`. `*(arrayA+1)[2]` translates to `**(arrayA+3)`, which is indeed an `int`.

Comment: !! Brilliant explanation

Answer (score 0):

We discuss about the int ** arrayA (2D).

arrayA is int ** , so arrayA+x is int ** too.

*arrayA or arrayA[i] is int *, and is a linear array(1D).

So, *(arrayA+1)[2], with any priority is a value not address.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the pointer correction, while you are free to declare a *pointer-to-pointer-to-int* (e.g. `int **arrayA;`), and allocate pointers, then allocate memory and assign the block to each individual pointer, there is no need to do so when dealing with a fixed number of elements in each row. You can simply declare a *pointer-to-array-of-type-no.* (e.g. `int (*arrayA)[10];` and allocate once. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ASZ 5

void *xmalloc (size_t s) {
    void *memptr = malloc (s);
    if (memptr == 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xmalloc() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return memptr;
}

int main (void) {

    int i, j;
    int (*arrayA)[ASZ] = xmalloc (sizeof *arrayA * ASZ);

    for (i = 0; i < ASZ; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ASZ; j++) {
            arrayA[i][j] = j+i;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ASZ; i++) {
        if (!i) putchar ('\n');
        for (j = 0; j < ASZ; j++) {
            printf (" %2d", arrayA[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    printf("\n *(arrayA+1)[2] = %d\n\n", *(arrayA+1)[2]);

    free (arrayA);

    return 0;
}
```

(don't forget to validate your memory allocation. using a helper like `xmalloc` can make life easier)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arr2dderef

  0  1  2  3  4
  1  2  3  4  5
  2  3  4  5  6
  3  4  5  6  7
  4  5  6  7  8

 *(arrayA+1)[2] = 3
```

Don't forget to validate your memory use with a memory error checking program such as `valgrind` on Linux, and don't forget to free the memory when it is no longer needed. (yes it is freed automatically on `exit`, but get in the habit now of accounting for each byte, and you will save yourself a lot of grief later)

```
$ valgrind ./bin/arr2dderef
==28392== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28392== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28392== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28392== Command: ./bin/arr2dderef
==28392==

  0  1  2  3  4
  1  2  3  4  5
  2  3  4  5  6
  3  4  5  6  7
  4  5  6  7  8

 *(arrayA+1)[2] = 3

==28392==
==28392== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28392==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28392==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 100 bytes allocated
==28392==
==28392== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28392==
==28392== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28392== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```